# Display FTP images in an app without having to download them

Tags: android, ftp, imageview

I am doing a project and I would like to display images which I take from and FTP and display them in a recycler view for example.
However I need to display about 50 images each FHD or higher res... I dont want to download all those images... 
Is there a way to do this without downloading them to my android device?
I have done some research and found out that I can do this with bitmaps.... However I havent done much work with bitmaps and havent studied them in Uni.
I got this code together from some older articles and I would appriciate if someone would be kind enough to check it and give me some insight if I have done something wrong.

I am sorry for my bad english.

```
public class async extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if(result != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result)
}
}
```

Comment: you can use universal image loader. https://medium.com/@ssaurel/enjoy-the-power-of-universal-image-loader-to-load-easily-your-images-on-android-3b36aa8a3161

Comment: @SanjayKumar This doesnt work with FTP